# docker inside nginx html folder can not create mounts

Tags: docker, ubuntu, nginx

I have a project which uses docker and it is hosted inside nginx root folder. When I run `docker-compose` to create solr container, I get an error when docker tries to create new folders inside the project root folder.

> Cannot start service (service): `error while creating mount source
>   path /path/to/targeted/folder read-only file system`

this is piece of docker-compose.yml file

```
solr-1:
    image: solr:7.4.0
    ports:
    - "8983:8983"
    volumes:
      - ./settings/solr/configsets:/opt/solr/server/solr/configsets
      - ./settings/solr/solr.in.sh:/opt/solr/bin/solr.in.sh
      - ./data/solr-master:/opt/solr/server/solr/sharq/data
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: I guess guys need your docker-compose.yml

Comment: i edited the question you can check piece of it

Comment: https://github.com/Illumina/hap.py/issues/48 , this might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

restart the docker solved the problem